# Runtime Upgrade: Transaction exhaust block limits

Tags: runtime-upgrade

I usually use `scheduler` to upgrade my runtime and it was working fine until now.

I have `Transaction exhaust block limits` trying to upgrade live chain. I build the wasm using `srtool v0.9.19`, and the compact wasm size is around `4.3Mb`. Then, I checked out my previous release commit and the wasm build at that commit is about `3.1Mb`, so maybe the size difference is the problem?

I also use `sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight` but the transaction is stuck at `broadcast` status on the Polkadot UI.

Parameters:

- Block Limits: 5Mb
- Block Weights: 1 seconds, since we're using 3 seconds block time

Please, any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: 4MB might get tight. The default length limit in the node template is 5MiB:
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/399efba55d82c6c8daff03ca900eb053c508eaeb/runtime/src/lib.rs#L139

Comment: So basically we need to upscale the block limit to 10Mib for example. But to do that we need to upgrade runtime. Now its kinda a loop

Comment: Hey @apopiak, I wonder whether we can upgrade the runtime using the .compact.compressed.wasm file?. I've seen the forkless runtime upgrade tutorials, it seems they all use the .compact.wasm file only.

Comment: @DanielLam, Yes you can and should use the `compact.compressed.wasm` and any tutorial that says to use a different file is just out of date.

Comment: @DanielLam was this issue resolved with the smaller Wasm file? if so please post that as an answer so others in the future can also learn from it

Comment: Sorry for the inactivity. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by using `.compact.compressed.wasm` produced by `srtool`. I believe using plain `cargo build` should also produce the `.compact.compressed.wasm`.

Thanks for the support

Answer (score -2):

You could

1. turn on lto to reduce the size of the wasm blob.

In `Cargo.toml`, add `lto = true` in the `[profile.release]` section:

```
[profile.release]
lto = true
```

This gives LLVM many more opportunities to inline and prune functions. Not only will it make the .wasm smaller, but it will also make it faster at runtime! The downside is that compilation will take longer.

2. tell LLVM to optimize for size instead of speed.

LLVM's optimization passes are tuned to improve speed, not size, by default. We can change the goal to code size by modifying the `[profile.release]` section in `Cargo.toml` to this:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 's'
```

Or, to even more aggressively optimize for size, at further potential speed costs:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 'z'
```

Note that, surprisingly enough, `opt-level = "s"` can sometimes result in smaller binaries than `opt-level = "z"`. Always measure!

3. Use the `wasm-opt` tool.

The Binaryen toolkit is a collection of WebAssembly-specific compiler tools. It goes much further than LLVM's WebAssembly backend does, and using its `wasm-opt` tool to post-process a `.wasm` binary generated by LLVM can often get another 15-20% savings on code size. It will often produce runtime speed ups at the same time!

```
# Optimize for size.

wasm-opt -Os -o output.wasm input.wasm

# Optimize aggressively for size.
wasm-opt -Oz -o output.wasm input.wasm

# Optimize for speed.
wasm-opt -O -o output.wasm input.wasm

# Optimize aggressively for speed.
wasm-opt -O3 -o output.wasm input.wasm
```

From my experience `wasm-opt` is able to reduce a `node_runtime.compact.wasm` from 4.3MB to 3.8 MB. Your mileage may vary.

```
$ du -sh ./target/release/wbuild/node-runtime/node_runtime.compact.wasm
4.3M    ./target/release/wbuild/node-runtime/node_runtime.compact.wasm
$ wasm-opt -Oz -o output.wasm ./target/release/wbuild/node-runtime/node_runtime.compact.wasm
$ du -sh output.wasm 
3.8M    output.wasm
```

References:

- https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/reference/code-size.html#shrinking-wasm-code-size

Edit: Sorry for lack of details on my first post attempt. I've added all the steps for you to follow and hope it works for you too.

Comment: `substrate-wasm-builder` seems already enable lto for wasm binary.

Comment: Tks for support @navigaid. However, I just use the `compressed wasm` for simplicity